# WPF C# Difficulties with Using a Dataview and DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working an application that uses a datagrid to display some items. These items are assigned a category ID. I need the application to work so that only a filtered view (that is, items belonging to the same category) are shown at a time.

To go about implementing this, I am using DataViews. However, the problem is that instead of displaying only the data I want (the columns Name, Price, Condition, and Image Path), I get a total of 11 columns - the four I want plus id, price, name, image, description, category, and conditionID. Basically, it is displaying not only what it is supposed to, but also all of the columns from my datatable.

Why is it doing this and how can I change this behavior. Also, how can I ensure the underlying DataSet is updated even though I am using DataViews?

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Leisurely_Diversion_Interface.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Leisurely_Diversion_Interface"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="conDictionary" ObjectType="{x:Type local:databaseAccess}" MethodName="getConditions" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid x:Name="itemGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding price}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Condition">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource conDictionary}}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Image Path" Binding="{Binding image}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Content="&lt;&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button x:Name="forwardButton"  Content="&gt;&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>


</Window>
```

MainWindow

```
namespace Leisurely_Diversion_Interface
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private int currentCategory;
        private int lowestBounds;
        private int upperBounds;
        private Dictionary<int, String> categoryMap;
        DataView view;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // attach events

            backButton.Click += navigate;
            forwardButton.Click += navigate;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            databaseAccess access = new databaseAccess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leisurelyDiversion"].ConnectionString);

            categoryMap = access.getCategories();
            var keyList = categoryMap.Keys.ToList();
            keyList.Sort();

            lowestBounds = (int)keyList[0];
            upperBounds = (int)keyList[keyList.Count - 1];
            currentCategory = lowestBounds;

            ds.Tables.Add(access.getTable("stock"));
            MessageBox.Show(currentCategory.ToString());
            view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            view.RowFilter = "category = " + currentCategory;

            itemGrid.ItemsSource = view;
        }

        private void navigate(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EVENT!"); 
            Button selected = (Button)sender;
            if (selected.Content == "<<")
            {
                currentCategory--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentCategory++;
            }
            view.RowFilter = "category = " + currentCategory;
            itemGrid.ItemsSource = view;
        }
    }
}
```

dataBaseAccess.cs

```
 class databaseAccess
    {
        private MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
        private MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();



        public databaseAccess(String connectionString)
        {
            try {         
                con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private bool connect()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                return true;
            } catch(MySqlException e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public DataTable getTable(String tableName)
        {
            if (this.connect())
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(table);

                con.Close();
                return table;

            }
            con.Close();
            return null;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, String> getConditions()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> conditionMap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            if (this.connect())
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM conditions", con);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        conditionMap.Add((int)reader["conditionID"], (string)reader["name"]);


                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return conditionMap;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, string> getCategories()
        {
            try { Dictionary<int, string> categoryMap = new Dictionary<int,string>();
            if (this.connect())
            {
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM categories", con);
                MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    categoryMap.Add((int)reader["id"], (string)reader["name"]);


                }
                con.Close();
                return categoryMap;
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); }
             return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

EDIT: The same thing happens when I use the following code:

```
     private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            databaseAccess access = new databaseAccess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leisurelyDiversion"].ConnectionString);

            categoryMap = access.getCategories();
            var keyList = categoryMap.Keys.ToList();
            keyList.Sort();

            lowestBounds = (int)keyList[0];
            upperBounds = (int)keyList[keyList.Count - 1];
            currentCategory = lowestBounds;

            ds.Tables.Add(access.getTable("stock"));



            itemGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "category = " + currentCategory;
        }

        private void navigate(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EVENT!"); 
            Button selected = (Button)sender;
            if (selected.Content == "<<")
            {
                currentCategory--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentCategory++;
            }
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "category = " + currentCategory;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. In this instance the fault was very simple. I neglected to turn set the AutoGenerateColumns property of the DataGrid to false.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="itemGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

After adding this, I used the second form of the code I posted and all seems to be working as it should.